# Is the story arc on "Supergirl" season 4 influenced by current political issues?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

Given some of the stuff going on, specially regarding immigration, has there been any comments by producers, writers or actors linking the show to the current political issues?

Reason I ask is while watching it, there seems to be a strong arc based on alien immigration and some themes that remind me of the US situation, including Russian collusion, “America First” and that sort of stuff.

Comment: It isn't stated directly, as far as I know, but it seems fairly obvious that this is the case. Take for instance the alien haters' cry of "Earth First!", mirroring Trump's "America First!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

Supergirl is very clearly making a stand on current political issues, and the showrunners have basically said as much on multiple occasions. I'm not going to list every single relevant interview, but here's one example:

> "Superman and Supergirl always were able to speak out for issues and for social justice. In a world where a lot of us are divided it's great to explore how a character like Supergirl can try and unite a divided people...We want to continue to tell stories that reflect the world we're living in."
>
> -Executive Producer Robert Rovner in an interview with [The Hollywood Reporter](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.hollywoodreporter.com/amp/live-feed/supergirl-season-4-preview-robert-rovner-interview-dc-tv-watch-1151734)